# Attempting to use np.insert in a created class which has subscripts yields "object does not support item assignment" debug

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have defined my own class which takes in any matrix and is defined in such a way to convert this matrix into three numpy arrays inside a parenthesis (which I assume means it's a tuple). Furthermore, I have added a **getitem** method which allows output arrays to be subscript-able just like normal arrays.

My class is called MatrixConverter, and say x is some random matrix, then:

```
q=MatrixConverter(x)
```

Where q gives:

```
q=(array[1,2,3,4],array[5,6,7,8],array[9,10,11,12])
```

(Note that this is just an example, it does not produce three arrays with consecutive numbers)

Then, for example, by my getitem method, it allows for:

```
q[0] = array[1,2,3,4]
q[0][1] = 2
```

Now, I'm attempting to design a method to add en element into one of the arrays using the np.insert function such as the following:

```
class MatrixConverter
#some code here
def __change__(self,n,x):
    self[1]=np.insert(self[1],n,x)
return self
```

Then, my desired output for the case where n=2 and x=70 is the following:

```
In:q.__change__(2,70)
Out:(array[1,2,3,4],array[5,6,70,7,8],array[9,10,11,12])
```

However, this gives me a TypeError: 'MatrixConverter' object does not support item assignment.

Any help/debugs? Should I perhaps use np.concentate instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, does your class implement `__setitem__`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, no? Could you elaborate

Comment: `np.insert` returns a new array.  If the error did not occur in that function (read the traceback) then that isn't part of the problem.  Does the `self[1]=...` work for anything?

Comment: @hpaulj the error occurs in the line ´self[1]=np.insert(self[1],n,x)´

Comment: Naturally, `self[i] = ...` won't work if the class doesn't support it. In other words, if it doesn't implement `__setitem__`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I have come code previously where I use self[i] and it works just like intended

Comment: Ok? I don't see how that's relevant. What I told you is a fact: No `__setitem__` means no `self[i] = ...`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey alright, could you perhaps help me to define setitem in my case?

Comment: Only if you show us more of your code. We have no idea how your `MatrixConverter` class is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to:

```
def __change__(self,n,x):
    temp = np.insert(self[1],n,x)
    self[1] = temp
return self
```

This will help you distinguish between a problem with the `insert` and a problem with the `self[1] = ...` setting.

I don't think the problem is with the `insert` call, but you need to write code that doesn't confuse you on such matters.  That's a basic part of debugging.

Beyond that you haven't given us enough code to help you.  For example what's the "getitem".

Expressions like `array[1,2,3,4]` tell me that you aren't actually copying from your code.  That's not a valid Python expression, or array display.